# Internet problem in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, internet, router

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04, and there is a problem with my wired internet
connection.

The weird thing is that it's not a driver problem, i guess, because it connects to my router, but does not receive any response from other servers.  The internet works just fine in Windows 7, or on my phone.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

I have a Dell Optiplex GX270, and a Serioux SRX-WR150WH wifi router.

/// EDIT

Here are the ouputs for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` :

`Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.1.1

search SRX`

and for `route -n` :

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0`

Also, here is a screenshot with my Connection Information, and the output of `ping 8.8.8.8`, which just goes on forever (I stopped it at around 430) :

[image]

Thanks.

PS I also tried running Ubuntu 13.04 liveUSB on my old laptop, and had the same results as with the computer, it connected to my router, but had no internet at all. Outputs are the same.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and edit your answer to include the outputs of these commands: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `route -n`.

Comment: May be a DNS issue. From the Network Connection icon in the menu bar, select 'Connection Information' - what are the properties there?

Comment: to check if DNS is the problem, go to the console (CTRL+ALT+T) and do a `ping 8.8.8.8` (the IP is one of Google's open DNS servers)

Comment: Seems your DNS settings are bad. Please check them. To check the DNS server settings, ping a URL like `ping www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Go to network manager > edit your connection > use static settings & check if it solve the problem  example use ip 192.168.1.25 , netmask 255.255.255.0 , gateway 192.168.1.1 , dns 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: Robert: If switching to static IP address and Google DNS nameserver addresses gives you full Internet access then the problem was probably bad configuration of the DHCP server and/or DNS server on your modemrouter. You should fix that problem and then switch back to Method: Automatic (DHCP). The modemrouter DHCP server supplies a nameserver address to the client. Check that the nameserver at that address is working properly. If it isn't working properly, either fix it or configure the DHCP server to supply the address of a working nameserver.